# Xamarin cloud apk error

Tags: c#, android, unit-testing, xamarin

I writing test for test cloud.

It passing well when I run it on pc.

Code of Test:

```
   using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Android;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace MurakamiKiev.UITests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        AndroidApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp ()
        {
            //app = ConfigureApp
            //.Android
            //.ApkFile("com.digitalmakers.murakamikiev-Signed.apk")
            //.PreferIdeSettings()
            //.StartApp();
            app = ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
        }


        [Test]
        public void AppLaunch()
        {

           // app.Repl();
           Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> bludodnyabuttonQuery = e => e.Id("bludodnya");

            //app.Flash(e => e.Id("bludodnya"));
            //app.Tap(e => e.Id("bludodnya"));

            app.WaitForElement(bludodnyabuttonQuery, "Timed out waiting for tapping bludo dnya");
            app.Tap(bludodnyabuttonQuery);



        }
    }
}
```

When I upload it on Xamarin Test Cloud I have test failed

This I have in log:

```
     SetUp Error : MurakamiKiev.UITests.Tests.AppLaunch
   SetUp : System.Exception : Multiple launchable acitivites configured in apk file, none was specified.  Available launchable activities: md5b02f34a74755c1c88b16cc48d7de656d.SplashActivity, com.digitalmakers.murakamikiev.MainActivity
  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.ApkFile.GetActivityToLaunchOrFail (System.String wantedActivity) <0x5a10808 + 0x0023f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.TestCloudAndroidAppInitializer.VerifyConfiguration () <0x5a10240 + 0x00083> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration) <0x58a6518 + 0x002a5> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp (AppDataMode appDataMode) <0x58a5a58 + 0x00063> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MurakamiKiev.UITests.Tests.SetUp () <0x58a47c8 + 0x00043> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
 at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x7e3070 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="2.6" package="com.digitalmakers.murakamikiev" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="43">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<application android:label="Murakami" android:icon="@drawable/icon3">

 android:largeHeap="true"

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBlOLY2SjQ6l7-O-wRuMeyD_QzwhIh-9x4" /><meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /></application>
<activity android:label="Murakami" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content.PM;
using System.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Gms.Analytics;

namespace MurakamiKiev
{

    [Activity(Label = "Murakami",Icon = "@drawable/logo", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        // Integrating Google Analitycs - start
        public class GAService
        {
            public string TrackingId = "UA-65673888-2";

            private static GoogleAnalytics GAInstance;
            private static Tracker GATracker;

            #region Instantiation ...
            private static GAService thisRef;
            private GAService()
            {
                // no code req'd
            }

            public static GAService GetGASInstance()
            {
                if (thisRef == null)
                    // it's ok, we can call this constructor
                    thisRef = new GAService();
                return thisRef;
            }
            #endregion

            public void Initialize(Context AppContext)
            {
                GAInstance = GoogleAnalytics.GetInstance(AppContext.ApplicationContext);
                GAInstance.SetLocalDispatchPeriod(10);

                GATracker = GAInstance.NewTracker(TrackingId);
                GATracker.EnableExceptionReporting(true);
                GATracker.EnableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
                GATracker.EnableAutoActivityTracking(true);
            }
        }
        // end of integrating Analitycs



        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {


            base.OnCreate (bundle);



            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            GAService.GetGASInstance().Initialize(this);

            // Sets images for the slider icons and their size



            Button sushi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sushi);
            Button sets = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.seti);
            //Button holodni = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.holodni);
            Button deserts = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.deserts);
            Button salads = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.salads);
            Button souces = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.souces);
            Button soupes = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.soupes);
            //Button goryachie = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.goryachie);
            Button lokshina = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.lokshina);
            Button lanchi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.lanchi);

            Button tepan = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.tepan);
            Button zakuski = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.zakuski);
            Button napoi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.napoi);
            Button osnovni = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.osnovni);
            Button sashimi = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.sashimi);


            Button rolli = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.rolli);
            ImageButton menu = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.menuButton);
            ImageButton cart = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.cartButton);

            //Otslezivaem click po knopke 'next' i perehodim dalshe
            souces.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(Souces));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            lanchi.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(Lanchi));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            zakuski.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(ZakuskiActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            sashimi.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(SashimiActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            osnovni.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(OsnovniBludaActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            napoi.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(NapitkiActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };

            lokshina.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(LapshaActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            /*goryachie.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(GoryachieZakuskiActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };*/
            soupes.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            salads.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib2 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib2.Vibrate (30);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(SaladsActivity));
                StartActivity (intent);
            };
            deserts.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib.Vibrate (30);
                var intent140 = new Intent (this, typeof(DesertsActivity));
                StartActivity (intent140);
            };
            rolli.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib3 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib3.Vibrate (30);
                var intent139 = new Intent (this, typeof(RolliKategorii));
                StartActivity (intent139);

            };
            sets.Click += delegate {
                Vibrator vib3 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib3.Vibrate (30);
                var intent121 = new Intent (this, typeof(SetsActivity));
                StartActivity (intent121);

            };
            sushi.Click += delegate {

                Vibrator vib4 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib4.Vibrate (30);
                var intent24 = new Intent (this, typeof(SushiActivity));
                StartActivity (intent24);

            };
            tepan.Click += delegate {

                Vibrator vib4 = (Vibrator)this.GetSystemService (Context.VibratorService);
                vib4.Vibrate (30);
                var intent24 = new Intent (this, typeof(Tepan));
                StartActivity (intent24);

            };

            //Otlezivaem click po knopke 'Korzina' i perehodim v nee
            cart.Click += delegate {
                var intent2 = new Intent (this, typeof(CartActivity));
                StartActivity (intent2);
            };
            menu.Click += delegate {
                var intent39 = new Intent (this, typeof(MenuTopActivity));
                ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
                editor.Clear();
                editor.Commit();
                StartActivity (intent39);

            };



            }
        }






        }
```

But I have `MainLauncher=true` only in SplashActivity!

How I can fix this error?

Help me please:(

Comment: Do you have any hardcoded manifest entries to `MainActivity`?

Comment: I can add Manifest file.

Comment: Done @SushiHangover

Comment: I am talking about the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you do not want to have manual entries in it concerning your activities if you are using class attributes (like `[Activity (MainLauncher=true)]`) to auto-generate them.

Comment: Also I added MainActivity code @SushiHangover

Comment: I need to delete something in manifest? @SushiHangover

Comment: Remove the <activity>....</activity> section, it is hardcoded to make that activity a `.LAUNCHER`... Using the class attribute that you have on your `MainActivity` will auto-generate it correctly.

Comment: Okay, I will try now.

Comment: If you now build and search the `obj` output directory, you can find the actual generated manifest file that is packaged into your apk and you should find your two activities (splash and main and only one of them should have the `.LAUNCHER` set). If you can not find it, just unzip the actual `.apk` and look at the one that is bundled in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114195/discussion-between---and-sushihangover).